# Additional Assumption in Munkres Problem on Continuous Functions

Tags: general-topology

One of the problems in Munkres is as follows:

Let $X$ and $X'$ denote a single set in the two topologies $\tau$ and $\tau$', respectively. Let $i: X' \rightarrow X$ be the identity function.

Show that $i$ is continuous $\iff \tau$' is finer than $\tau$.

In order to do this problem, do you need to assume that $\tau$ and $\tau$' are comparable? If not, how can you show that they are comparable?

Comment: You do not need to assume anything.

Comment: I presume you mean that $\tau$ is the topology on $X$ and similarly for $X'$?

Comment: I think from the problem statement, $\tau$ and $\tau$' are both on some unspecified set, and X and X' are both subsets of that larger set.

Comment: What the problem means is this: ``Let $\tau$ and $\tau'$ be two topologies on the same set $X$. Let $i: (X,\tau)\to (X,\tau')$ be the identity function. Show that $i$ is continuous $\iff$ $\tau'$ is finer than $\tau$.''  You don't need to assume that the two topologies are comparable; this will be part of your conclusion.

Comment: So when Munkres writes "Let X and X' denote a single set", this means X and X' are two representations for the same set, and not two different sets?

Comment: @PaulHlebowitsh He means, let $X$ and $X'$ be two topological spaces whose underlying sets are the same, but with different topologies (collections of open subsets).

Comment: For some reason, this explanation clicked with me. I now understand what I was doing wrong. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

If $i$ is continuous, then $i^{-1}U = U \in \tau'$ for all $U \in \tau$, hence $\tau \subset \tau'$.

If $\tau \subset \tau'$ and $U \in \tau$, then $i^{-1}U = U \in \tau'$, hence $i$ is continuous.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have been necessary to actually do the exercise for him.

Comment: @RyanReich: I just wanted to point out that you don't need to worry about what $X,X'$ are.